# ¿Se podría usar el metodo __eq__ en una clase para comparar las keys de un diccionario en python?

Tags: python

```
class Product:
        und={}

        def __init__(self,code,descripcion,precio):
                self.code = code
                self.descripcion = descripcion
                self.precio=precio
              
        def __str__(self):
                return "El codigo es  {} con la descripcion {} ".format(self.code, self.descripcion)

        def agregar_uni(self,code,descripcion,precio):
                self.und[code]=descripcion,precio

        def mostrar_todos(self):
                print("Las unidades  son: ")
                for i in self.und.keys():
                        print("Code: "+str(i))
                        print("Descripcion: "+str(self.und[i]))
                        
              
                     
        def __eq__(self,product):
               return self.code == product.code
class Catalogue():
        def __init_-(self):
               self.catalogo{}
        def add_product(self):
```

""" Aquí es donde debo de comparar los códigos de los diferentes productos que están en le diccionario.Según el enunciado con el método (**eq**). ¿Habría alguna forma de comparación de las keys del diccionario creado más arriba?

```
t = Product(code="1",descripcion="Llaves Allen",precio="40€")
#print(t)
t.agregar_uni("1","LLave inglesa","40€")
t.agregar_uni("2","Llaves Allen","40€")
t.mostrar_todos()
```

Comment: Necesitas básicamente encontrar duplicados.? o h acer que sean "code" unicos.?

Comment: Encontrar duplicados. Por lo que he leído el método __eq__ sirve para realizar comparaciones. En el enunciado del ejercicio que estoy haciendo, me obliga a poner ese método. Tengo que realizar una clase de productos; y he pensado que guardando esos productos en un diccionario sería más factible. Lo que no sé es cómo hacer la comparación con ese método.

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. La función "__eq__" se usan cuando tienes dos objetos de la misma clase (ejemplo, clase Alumno) y quieres ver si son o no el mismo alumno: if alumno1 == alumno2. A primera vista tu definición de __eq__ está OK, aunque faltan validaciones (por ejempo, chequear que "product" sea un objeto de clase "Product".

Comment: Candid Moe gracias por contestar. Me comentas algo muy interesante; ¿Cómo compararlas/ chequeas que el producto esté en la clase Producto? . Te agradecería la ayuda.

Comment: No debes crear un objeto para guardar todos tus productos, tienes que instanciar esa clase para cada producto y comparar de una instancia a otra.